# How i put a list of ips address in PHP without overwrite?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$file = "ips.txt";
$ip = get_ip_address();
$content = "$ip";
$content =  $ip."\n";
$texto = $content;
$fp = fopen($file, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $texto);
fclose($fp);
```

and i want6 a result like this in my ips.txt:

```
 000.00.00.1
 000.00.00.2
 000.00.00.3
```

when i enter with the first ip it write it,ok. BUT the secong ip overwrites it
any solution?thanks

Comment: Why did you use python tags ?

Comment: on subsequent writes you should open the handler in "append mode". See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php or use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: One line wonder: `file_put_contents( 'ips.txt', get_ip_address() ."\n", FILE_APPEND );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

So use 'a' :

> 'a'   Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the end of the file**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

```
$fp = fopen($file, "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) here to get the content of the file and append some new text.

```
$file = "ips.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$ip = get_ip_address();
$content .= ($ip . "\n");
$fp = fopen($file, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: does not change line. It copy everything on the same line.

Comment: this copy it next to the first ip

Answer (score 0):

You could use file_put_content, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
<?php

$file = "ips.txt";
file_put_contents($file, get_ip_address() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

The $ip . PHP_EOL will give you a line break in accordance with your OS.
The FILE_APPEND flag will make sure you do not overwrite the file.